# Fos Facebook bundle integrate without FOS user bundle in symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

Does anyone have some tutorials on how can I integrate FOS-Facebook bundle without use of the FOSUser Bundle?

Comment: when you install just the fos Facebook bundle it's not ok ? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle

Comment: you can use HWIOAuthBundle to login with facebook

Comment: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/resource_owners/facebook.md

Comment: I think there is no dependency between FOSuserBundle and FosFacebook bundle. You can use FosFacebook bundle freely.

Comment: Facebook bundle is installed but cant figure out how to integrate it without use of FOS User Bundle. :)

Comment: @ahmedhamdy sorry but my basic requiremnt is to use only FOS Facebook bundle.

Comment: @hizbul25 do u have any sample code for this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle follow this

Comment: i have checked above link's documentation but they have only tutorial for integrating with FOS User bundle. not for other type of user.

Answer (score 0):

This Bundle has been DEPRECATED consider using https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle instead